# How can I highlight multiple span tags on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, highlight

I'm not sure if it is possible but,
if I put some text inside  tags like this;

`The quick <span>brown</span> fox jumps <span>over</span> the angry dog`

and i have this in css;

```
span:hover{ 
    background-color: green;
}
```

how can i make it that when i hover over 'brown' or 'over', they both become highlighted?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using js.

Comment: Simply use this; div:hover span{ 
    background-color: green;
}

Answer (score 3):

There is no [previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector), You could either  use [General sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to target the following `<span>`s like so:

```css
span:hover,
span:hover ~ span {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/barim/2/edit)**

Or fire the `:hover` effect on entire line, wrap them by an additional element e.g. `<p>` and then use `:hover` pseudo-element for the wrapper like so:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/barim/1/edit)**

```
<p>The quick <span>brown</span> fox jumps <span>over</span> the angry dog</p>
```

```css
p:hover span { 
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: This will also change the background when you 'hover' other words too, such as 'dog', right ?

Comment: This solution will come into action when he hove the "The quick" text also.

Comment: siblings selector will work only for next siblings not previous one.

Comment: ok so the first thing you said worked really well, except when i moved the cursor onto the second or third span-ed words the ones in front of it unhightlighted.also what does ~ do? i have never seen it before –

Comment: @thyme `A ~ B` matches B only if it is preceded by A while they're siblings.

Comment: @thyme Unfortunately there's no previous sibling selector in CSS as I mentioned. However I'll update the answer if I find a CSS solution.

Comment: do you think it would work if i gave each span a different class and then linked them all together using ~ ?

Answer (score 1):

The exact behaviour you are looking for can't be achieved only with CSS but it can be achieved with simple jQuery :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/x98oc0cu/)**

```
$('span').hover(function(){
    $('span').css("background-color", "green");
}, function(){
    $('span').css("background-color", "none");
});
```

If you have several sentences, you use : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/x98oc0cu/1/)**

```
$('span').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('span').css("background-color", "green");
}, function(){
    $(this).parent().children('span').css("background-color", "none");
});
```

Comment: where would i put that? i have never used jQuery before

Comment: @thyme I won't be able to explain that in the comments but you can find the basics of using jQuery on this page http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 1):

I was about to post the same as web-tiki... but adding a class for the span insteed of css property as I like it better for future changes on the "hover" effect using just the css sheet

```
$("span").hover(function() {
$('span').addClass( "SpanClass2" );
}, function() {
$('span').removeClass( "SpanClass2" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wr1z8h0a/1/

Comment: Class change is a good idea +1. for several sentences, you can do http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wr1z8h0a/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbwgoL99/)**

```
div:hover span{ 
    background-color: green;
}
```

good luck!